# Apache PIG - How to get the Flop 10 data records?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop2

I have data records like this:

```
Name          customerID revenue(Mio) premium          
Michael James 078932832  2.7          y
Susan Miller  024383490  3.9          n
John Cooper   021023023  2.1          y
```

How do I get the records - divided into the premium flag - each with the lowest revenue (=Flop 10)?

The result should be given as:

```
Nr Name          customerID revenue(Mio) premium          
1  John Cooper   021023023  2.1          y
2  Michael James 078932832  2.7          y
3  Andrew Murs   044834399  3.0          y
.  ...           .....      ...          .
10 th entry      with       flag         y

1  Susan Miller  024383490  3.9          n
.  ...           .....      ...          .
10 th entry      with       flag         n
```

As you see the list is ordered ascending (beginning with the lowest revenue).

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use split
Considering A is your load statement

```
A = load 'data' as (Nr,Name,customerID,revenue,premium);
B = split A into PRE if premium =='y', NONPRE if premium == 'n';
C = order PRE by revenue asc;
D = order NONPRE by revenue asc;
```

Disclaimer: Be careful while using split as null records get dropped. I have not compiled this code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it. But how can I get the two different results in one file?#

Comment: E = UNION C,D; DUMP E;